# Передвижение объектов в VB 6.0

Tags: visual-basic

Вот скажите, у меня есть картинка (игрока и монстра), я знаю, как сделать чтобы игрок мог передвигаться, но не знаю, как сделать чтобы моб смог двигаться САМ, т.е он передвигается вперед, назад, влево, вправо, когда моб подходит к концу формы, то он как бы отталкивался от неё и продолжал движение?

Answer (score 1):

Запускаете таймер (ведь в VB есть таймер?) с интервалом, например, полсекунды, и в обработчике события тика таймера рандомно или по какой-нибудь причине (например, можно смещать монстра ближе к игроку, или ещё как-нибудь) перемещаете картинку монстра, при этом не забывая проверять, не вышла ли ещё картинка за край формы, если выходит - перемещаете обратно. Пример *псевдокода* (т.к. с VB знаком поверхностно):

> процедура "форма создана"
> {запускаем таймер}
> процедура "нажали клавишу"
> {перемещаем картинку игрока в сторону, соответствующую нажатой клавише}
> процедура "тик таймера"
> {1. генерируем случайное число от одного до четырёх
> 2. если при передвижении в сторону, соответствующую полученному числу, картинка монстра выйдет за край формы, то возвращаемся к шагу 1.
> 3. перемещаем картинку монстра в соответствующую полученному числу сторону}

Ну, вы меня, надеюсь, поняли. Это событийно-ориентированный вариант, в структурно-ориентированном будет по-сложнее, но в общем-то тоже: бесконечный цикл (в котором могут заодно обрабатываться нажатия клавиш) анализирует и изменяет положение картинки, в данном случае монстра.
P.S. На счёт цифр. Цифра 1, например, означает движение вверх, а далее по часовой стрелке: 2 - вправо, 3 - вниз, 4 - влево. Можно использовать другие способы, но это, на мой взгляд, наиболее простой.